# How to find distinct rows in a whatsapp messages table?

Tags: sql

I have a table named whatsapp_messages where i have the columns sender_id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), receiver_id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). I am trying to find all the distinct conversations. Here, if sender 1 sends a message to receiver 2 its a conversation. And vice versa is not a different convseration, but same conversation.

I am stuck. Anyone with an idea ?

MY CODE:

```
with convos as (
        select w.message_receiver_id,w.message_sender_id, (case when message_receiver_id <> message_sender_id
                    then 1 else 0 end) as conversations
            from whatsapp_messages w 
)
select *
from convos
```

Comment: Please include some sample data and your desired result

Comment: mysql and postgresql are two different database products with different features. Which one do you use? How is your question related to data science and ML? Neither Postgresql nor mysql support ML directly, you need additional extensions

Answer (score 0):

canonicalize the position of columns based on the data in them:

```
select distinct 
   least(message_receiver_id,message_sender_id),  
   greatest(message_receiver_id,message_sender_id)
from conversations
...
```